# Nome de um arquivo redirecionando a entrada padrão em C

Tags: c

Como armazenar em uma variável o nome de um arquivo quando redireciono a entrada padrão, sem usar **argv**.

Exemplo de execução:

> ./a.out < nomearquivo.txt

Comment: Isto não é uma pergunta de _shell_?

Comment: Não, o problema surge quando coloco o simbolo de menor para redirecionar a entrada, caso a execução seja ./a.out nomearquivo.txt o argc conta 2 e conta 1 executando ./a.out < nomearquivo.txt

Comment: Claro; o redirecionamento é uma particularidade do _shell_.